# Merge Contiguous date ranges that are from same id and have same amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following dataset where person has id and their amount can change over time so changes are recorded as date ranges. Sometimes there are gaps in date ranges where there is no information available. It is fine. However I want to merge continuous date ranges where they happen to have same amount while it is spanned over multiple records like row 2 and 3 for ID = 1.

```
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (
    ID [int] NULL,
    StartDate [date] NULL,
    EndDate [date] NULL,
    Amount [decimal](12,2) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @DataTable
SELECT 1, '20180101','20180513', 10.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20180630','20190301', 15.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20190302','20190615', 15.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20190616','20991231', 5.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20190101','20190331', 35.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20190401','20191031', 30.00  UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20180505','20180930', 19.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20181001','20190228', 1.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20190501','20190815', 1.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20190819','20190827', 5.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20190828','20991231', 1.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2017-10-01', '2017-12-31',   688.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2018-01-01', '2018-04-30',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-31',   783.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2018-06-01', '2018-12-31',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2019-01-01', '2019-03-31',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2019-04-01', '2019-04-30',   571.46 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2019-05-01', '2019-06-30',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '2019-07-01', '2099-12-31',   707.96
;
```

[image: Image of table]

I solved it by generating date lines between start and end date using dimDate and then kept record where either amount changed from previous record or there is gap of dates for ID. Then I used next record date available to use that for end date. Query is as follows:

```
WITH DateList AS (
SELECT DT.*, DD.DateOnly AS RecordDate
FROM @DataTable DT
INNER JOIN dimDate DD ON DT.StartDate <= DD.DateOnly AND CASE WHEN DT.EndDate > GETDATE() THEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) ELSE DT.EndDate END >= DD.DateOnly
)

, PrevValue AS (
SELECT 
    *
    , LAG(RecordDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RecordDate) AS PrevDate
    , LAG(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RecordDate) AS PrevAmt
FROM DateList 
)
, KeepHistory AS (
SELECT 
    *
FROM PrevValue
WHERE Amount <> PrevAmt OR PrevAmt IS NULL OR DATEADD(DAY,1,PrevDate) <> RecordDate OR PrevDate IS NULL
)
, FINAL AS (
SELECT 
    *
    , LEAD(PrevDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartDate) AS NextEndDate
FROM KeepHistory
)

SELECT 
    ID 
    , StartDate
    , CASE WHEN NextEndDate > EndDate THEN NextEndDate ELSE EndDate END AS EndDate
    , Amount
FROM FINAL
```

[image: Final result with row 2 and 3 are merged into 2]

My question is there an alternative way to approach this without going through dimDate or generating dates between start and end date. Can I achieve this simply by using window functions like gap and island problem like [here](https://bertwagner.com/2019/03/12/gaps-and-islands/)?

Please let me know if you see any issues with my current solution.
Thanks.

About @Larnu response, your updated query works for most . I added ID = 4 example that seems to cause an issue when merging its 4th and 5th row. It also merges 7th row when 6th row has different amount.

[ID = 4 4th, 5th and 7th are merged; 6th one has different amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIzxx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
WITH Gaps AS(
    SELECT DT.ID,
           DT.StartDate,
           DT.EndDate,
           DT.Amount,
           DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(DATEADD(DAY,1,DT.EndDate),1,DT.StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY DT.ID, DT.Amount ORDER BY DT.StartDate ASC), DT.StartDate) AS Gap
    FROM @DataTable DT),
Grps AS(
    SELECT G.ID,
           G.StartDate,
           G.EndDate,
           G.Amount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.ID ORDER BY G.StartDate) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.ID,Amount ORDER BY G.StartDate) + Gap AS Grp
    FROM Gaps G)
SELECT G.ID,
       MIN(G.StartDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate,
       G.Amount
FROM Grps G
GROUP BY G.ID,
         G.Amount,
         G.Grp
ORDER BY ID,
         StartDate;
```

Added a Unique ID, to get around a "feature":

```
DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (
    UniqueID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    ID [int] NULL,
    StartDate [date] NULL,
    EndDate [date] NULL,
    Amount [decimal](12,2) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @DataTable
SELECT 1, '20180101','20180513', 10.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20180630','20190301', 15.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20190302','20190615', 15.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20190616','20991231', 5.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20190101','20190331', 35.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20190401','20191031', 30.00  UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20180505','20180930', 19.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20181001','20190228', 1.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20190501','20190815', 1.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20190819','20190827', 5.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20190828','20991231', 1.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20171001', '20171231',   688.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20180101', '20180430',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20180501', '20180531',   783.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20180601', '20181231',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20190101', '20190331',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20190401', '20190430',   571.46 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20190501', '20190630',   707.96 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20190701', '20991231',   707.96;

--SELECT *
--FROM @DataTable;

WITH Gaps AS(
    SELECT DT.UniqueID,
           DT.ID,
           DT.StartDate,
           DT.EndDate,
           DT.Amount,
           DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(DATEADD(DAY,1,DT.EndDate),1,DT.StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY DT.ID, DT.Amount ORDER BY DT.UniqueID ASC), DT.StartDate) AS Gap
    FROM @DataTable DT),
Grps AS(
    SELECT G.UniqueID,
           G.ID,
           G.StartDate,
           G.EndDate,
           G.Amount,
           G.Gap,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.ID ORDER BY G.UniqueID) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.ID,Amount ORDER BY G.UniqueID) + (Gap * UniqueID) AS Grp
    FROM Gaps G)
SELECT G.ID,
       MIN(G.StartDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate,
       G.Amount
FROM Grps G
GROUP BY G.ID,
         G.Amount,
         G.Grp
ORDER BY ID,
         StartDate;
```

Comment: It looks like it is merging 8th and 9th row where there is a gap in date range. Although 8th and 9th row share same amount, End Date in 8th row is 02/08/2019 while start date in 9th row is 05/01/2019.

Comment: Hey @Larnu Thank you very much. Your query works for most except for one scenario I came up with. In my original response, I added ID = 4 record with outcome provided as image. I tried to play around with your query to try to fix this but had no luck so far. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I used "12/31/2099" when I was running with your query. I just typed it wrong as 9999. I will fix it now.

Comment: it is not about date overflow error that can be caused when 12/31/9999 is used. 4th, 5th and 7th row are still getting merged with 6th row has different amount.

Comment: image is the outcome from your query. I added extra rows for ID = 4 in first query above that is loading "DataTable" table variable.

Comment: That really changes the ball park, @blitzboxer. That isn't continuous dates anymore...

Comment: I don't think you are following what I am saying. data is still available in the first query that is loading that table variable. Don't look at that image for the data. Image is the outcome after running data through your query.

Comment: How are 4th ('2018-06-01','2018-12-31', 707.96), 5th ('2019-01-01','2019-03-31', 707.96) and 7th row ('2019-05-01', '2019-06-30', 707.96) are continuous? 4th and 5th row are continuous but why 7th row is merged while 6th row has different amount ('2019-04-01','2019-04-30',571.46). I get what you are doing with your query for good majority but when there are multiple occurrence of record with abrupt gap with different amount. It fails in that situation.

Comment: I am referring to ID = 4's  4th, 5th, 6th and 7th rows that are 16th, 17th, 18th, and 19th in that table. I did not change anything from ID = 1,2,3 for which you built the query for. I just added new example for ID = 4 that could potentially cause query to not work when same amount appearing multiple times with break. Sorry if numbering like that caused any confusion.

Comment: Maybe that @blitzboxer .

Comment: While this one no longer overlaps them, it still does not merge 15th and 16th row and merge 18th with 19th row. Can you explain what you did because somehow it works for 2nd and 3rd row but no longer works for those cases?

Comment: Honestly, @blitzboxer. I'm out. If you unaccept the asnwer, I'll happyily delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursion as follows

```
    DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (
        ID [int] NULL,
        StartDate [date] NULL,
        EndDate [date] NULL,
        Amount [decimal](12,2) NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO @DataTable
    SELECT 1, '20180101','20180513', 10.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '20180630','20190301', 15.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '20190302','20190615', 15.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '20190616','20991231', 5.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '20190101','20190331', 35.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '20190401','20191031', 30.00  UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '20180505','20180930', 19.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '20181001','20190228', 1.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '20190501','20190815', 1.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '20190819','20190827', 5.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '20190828','20991231', 1.00;


    ;with cte as(
    select t1.id,
t1.startDate,
t1.EndDate,
t1.Amount,
     row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t1.Id,t1.startDate) R#  
from @DataTable t1
    left outer join @DataTable t2 on dateadd(d,-1,t1.startdate)=t2.enddate and t1.Amount=t2.Amount
    and t1.id=t2.id
    where t2.amount is null),
    cte1 as
    (select 
t1.id,
t1.startDate,
t1.EndDate,
t1.Amount,
t1.R# from cte t1

    union all

    select t1.id,
    t2.startdate,
t1.endDate, 
t1.amount,
R# from @DataTable t1 inner join cte1 t2
    on dateadd(d,-1,t1.startdate)=t2.enddate and t1.Amount=t2.Amount)
    select id,
min(stArtdate)[startdate],
max(enddate)[enddate],
min(amount)[amount] from cte1 GROUP by R#,id 
    Order  by id,max(enddate)
```

Comment: Some whitespace and line breaks would make that readable. No offence, but it's a mess at the moment. Also [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). `t2` could mean `@DataTable` or `cte1` in that query

Comment: It does, also, seem bit overkill to scan the table 4 times, rather than once.